# Infinite scroll in lightning datatable in LWC increments offset multiple times

Tags: lightning-datatable

Infinite scroll in LWC datatable is calling the `loadMoreData()` function multiple times. This increments the offset multiple times but wire is not called multiple times and hence some data gets skipped while loading. Also, the spinner at the end is not showing. I used wire to get the data from database. I am not able to figure out why datatable is making multiple function calls. I did research but was not able to figure out the reason. Please guide. Thanks!

I checked these sites:

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation
2. https://salesforcespace.blogspot.com/2020/02/lwc-audit-log-viewer-using-infinite.html

**HTML**

```html
<div class="slds-table_col-bordered slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped" style="height:15rem;">
                        <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={data} columns={columns} onrowselection={handleRowActions} default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
                        sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                        sorted-by={sortedBy}
                        onsort={onHandleSort}
                        enable-infinite-loading
                        onloadmore={loadMoreData}>
                        </lightning-datatable>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
@wire(downloadRelatedListControllerLWC, { Id: '$recordId',PageSize: '$PageSize',counterLWC:'$counter' }) wired(result) {
        window.console.log('in wire - pagesize:'+this.PageSize+'counter:'+this.counter);
        this.refreshTable = result; //for refreshing the datatable
        //rest of wire code here
}


loadMoreData(event) {
        window.console.log('inside load more data');
        event.target.isLoading = true; //showing the spinner
        if(this.count.data > this.counter){
            event.target.isLoading = false; //hiding the spinner
            window.console.log('incrementing counter'+this.counter);
            this.counter=this.counter+10; //This statement is called multiple times. Hence offset is incremented multiple times
            window.console.log('incremented counter'+this.counter);
            return refreshApex(this.refreshTable); //calling the wire. Wire is not called multiple times when offset is incremented. Offset is incremented 2-3 times and then wire is incremented
        } 
}
```

**Debug logs:**

Red represents scrolls and yellow represents calls

[image]

**Updates**

If I use constructor instead of wire to access apex code, I get the following error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the example from the documentation, I think, using an imperative apex will be more appropriate here. So you need to fetch more data whenever load more data is called, then concatenate that to the original `data` attribute which is bound to the table. Refer to the below example from the documentation. I have added some comments(starting with `// **`) to that.

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 500px">
        <lightning-datatable
                columns={columns}
                data={data}
                key-field="id"
                enable-infinite-loading
                onloadmore={loadMoreData}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
    {loadMoreStatus}
</template>
```

**Javascript:**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class DatatableExample extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    @track columns = columnsDefs;
    @track loadMoreStatus;
    @api totalNumberOfRows;

    loadMoreData(event) {
            //Display a spinner to signal that data is being loaded
            event.target.isLoading = true;
            //Display "Loading" when more data is being loaded
            this.loadMoreStatus = 'Loading';
            fetchData(50) /// ** call your apex method here.
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.length >= this.totalNumberOfRows) {
                        event.target.enableInfiniteLoading = false;
                        this.loadMoreStatus = 'No more data to load'; // ** end of data
                    } else {
                        const currentData = this.data;
                        //Appends new data to the end of the table
                        const newData = currentData.concat(data); // ** concat data
                        this.data = newData; // ** replace data.
                        this.loadMoreStatus = '';
                    }
                    event.target.isLoading = false;
                }));
        }
}
```

Comment: I honestly think imperative apex is always the safest approach instead of `@wire`, if this your experience as well? When do you choose @wire over imperative?

Comment: If I use an imperative function, I'll have to call it in the constructor to load initial data. I use @api recordId and it cannot be used in constructor. Hence I'll need wire.

Comment: @AtlasCan
For fetching data from the database, my first preference is wired methods. wire methods save a lot of work on customization. Also, it is faster as it loads data from the cache. You can use `refreshApex` whenever you want to get data from the database. It reloads data and rerenders every dependent component if any of the attribute(parameter)'s value is changed.

 The primary use of imperative apex is DML operations. Also, there are exceptions where you cannot use `refreshApex` and you want to skip the cache while getting the data, like the one in this post, then use imperative.

Comment: @Koustubh did you get any error when you used `recordId` in the constructor?

Comment: I have done the data concatenation that you talked about. The problem is that the counter is incremented multiple times and wire is called only once.

Comment: @rahulgawale Yes. I have updated the question with the error I get on using recordId in constructor.

Comment: @Koustubh instead of constructor use connectedCallback() to call imperative method.

Comment: Thank you @rahulgawale

Comment: @Koustubh Did it work for you?

Comment: @rahulgawale Yes!! connectedCallback() is working. Thanks to you... Cheers!

Comment: @Koustubh please mark it as accepted. It will be helpful for other people.