# Infinite Scroll In LWC DataTable Using @wire Getting Error For FetchData

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter, scrolling

The Salesforce documentation for [LWC datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) indicates fetchData(50) but doesn't define it. In my case I am using @wire(apexMethod) to populate the data but getting understandable error

> fetchData is not defined

I'm not even clear if this has to be done completely differently given that I am using @wire for the table data with a general `SELECT <Confirmations__c> WHERE...` and getting all data at once.

```
export default class recordTableLastMonthConfirmations extends LightningElement {
  error;
  columns = columns;
  loadMoreStatus;
  @api totalNumberOfRows;

  @wire(getConfirmationList)
  confirmations;

  handleSave(event) {
    this.saveDraftValues = event.detail.saveDraftValues;
  }

  // The method onsort event handler
  onHandleSort(event) {
    var fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
    var sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
    this.sortedBy = fieldName;
    this.sortedDirection = sortDirection;
    this.confirmations = this.sortData(fieldName, sortDirection);
  }

  // Supports infinite scrolling
  loadMoreData(event) {
    //Display a spinner to signal that data is being loaded
    event.target.isLoading = true;
    //Display "Loading" when more data is being loaded
    this.loadMoreStatus = 'Loading';
    fetchData(50).then((confirmations) => {
      if (confirmations.length >= this.totalNumberOfRows) {
        event.target.enableInfiniteLoading = false;
        this.loadMoreStatus = 'No more data to load';
      } else {
        const currentData = this.confirmations;
        //Appends new data to the end of the table
        const newData = currentData.concat(confirmations);
        this.confirmations = newData;
        this.loadMoreStatus = '';
      }
      event.target.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

The table loads fine but throws the error in scratch org and just hangs on the spinner in preview.
Tried:

1. fetch(confirmations)(50).then((confirmations)
2. fetchConfirmations(50).then((confirmations)

Seen these sites but they are not using @wire to populate the table or slightly different issues:

1. [Infinite scroll in lightning datatable in LWC increments offset multiple times](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/299355/infinite-scroll-in-lightning-datatable-in-lwc-increments-offset-multiple-times)
2. [LWC lightning-datatable Infinite Scrolling Not Working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279776/lwc-lightning-datatable-infinite-scrolling-not-working)

What is the proper method for the loadMoreData(event) in this case?

Comment: where is your fetchData method? as the error states, it is missing in your code.

Comment: My question is I don't understand how to construct it in this case. It is completely missing from the SF Docs on this element hence a number of questions in SE on the topic. Initially I assumed it was a native method since not included by SF, but have now figured that to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchData` is simply an example method used in the doc, indicating that you should define a method to "fetch more data".

Basically, you need handle the "fetching data" part with your own function.

Comment: Because there is a ```fetch``` javascript function and the SF docs also have a ```data``` function in the same example I thought maybe I should be using them together somehow. I will construct a method then.